# Simple MYSQL Update in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I try to make simple MySQL update in PYTHON, as soon as I am completly new in this there is big chance i did some crazy mystake here.

When I make an update on some specific ID nothing change in DB (even console say that 0 rows changed)

Can someone look at it and give me advise what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

p.s. using mysqlclient and python 3.4.3 if it's relevant

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import MySQLdb as mdb

con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'audatexcz');
with con:

    cur = con.cursor()

    cur.execute("UPDATE Writers SET Name = %s WHERE Id = %s",
        ("Guy de Matis", "4"))

    print ("Number of rows updated:",  cur.rowcount)
```

console answer:

```
Number of rows updated: 0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: did you try in this mysql

Comment: what you mean by "this" mysql I ask in question? I did , there is even output in console for it :)

Comment: `con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'audatexcz',autocommit=True)` try this try printing cur.fetchall()

Comment: Number of rows updated: 0

Comment: There will be no output for update query just see the table to see if any thing is changed

Comment: yea, I always check the table first, there is no change there. I really expect this is some stupid kind of ERROR, already double check all names like DB / user/ table /column. Don't know what else I can check

Comment: Try a select query and see if you can get the old values through python program that is

Comment: `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Writers")

    rows = cur.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        print (row[1])`
I try this which succesfull return names. That names without update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replicated your situation and cannot reproduce your issue.  Also on Python 3.4.3 - fresh install of `mysqlclient`.  See console output below.  I wonder if maybe our column types don't match (my `Id` column was created using `INT` keyword), or maybe you have a typo in your capitalisation?  For example - is your column name `id` rather than `Id` ?

```
>>> con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'rsnape', '<my_password>', 'testdb');
>>> with con:
...     cur = con.cursor()
...     cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Writers")
...     rows = cur.fetchall()
...     for row in rows:
...         print(row)
...
5
(1, 'a')
(2, 'b')
(3, 'c')
(4, 'd')
(5, 'e')
>>> with con:
...     cur = con.cursor()
...     cur.execute("UPDATE Writers SET Name = %s WHERE Id = %s",
...         ("Guy de Matis", "4"))
...     print("number of rows",cur.rowcount)
...
1
number of rows 1
>>> with con:
...     cur = con.cursor()
...     cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Writers")
...     rows = cur.fetchall()
...     for row in rows:
...         print(row)
...
5
(1, 'a')
(2, 'b')
(3, 'c')
(4, 'Guy de Matis')
(5, 'e')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could that you are passing a string value for `id` rather than an integer value. Try instead

```
cur.execute("UPDATE Writers SET Name = %s WHERE Id = %s",
                 ("Guy de Matis", 4))
```

Though @JRichardSnape's answer suggests that isn't necessary, so this is something of a long shot.

Answer (score -1):

Add the single quotes, besides, read the return value directly.

```
cur = con.cursor()
rowsAffected = cur.execute("UPDATE Writers SET Name='%s' WHERE Id='%s'", ("Guy de Matis", "4"))
print ("Number of rows updated:",  rowsAffected)
```

Comment: Single quotes would be required if you were generating SQL queries by string interpolation, but that opens SQL injection vulnerabilities. The driver will make the correct substitutions according to the values passed in the second argument to `.execute()`.

Comment: @liushuaikobe i try this as well, unfotunately doesnt help, I'm really not sure in this but this should be "Prepare" statement like PDO in PHP which should alove add varaibiles without ''

Comment: @Andurit AO are you sure there's a row whose `Id` is 4?

Comment: there are 5 rows there, from 1 to 5